# How do I call a text file to be used in my python terminal script

Tags: python, linux, terminal

I wrote a binary decoder in python but i'm having trouble getting the text file through to it.

```
"""

Date :28/3/17
File Name:binary_to_string.py

"""

import sys


def binary_to_str(binary_string):
    """
    This function take a binary string as argument and convert to string
    :param binary_string: string in 0 or 1 from
    :return:
    """
    bits = 8  # initialize bit to 8 means by default we are assuming  8 bit binary
    # checking  for backslash if we found first 8 bit give backslash then we reassign  bit to 7
    if ord(chr(int(binary_string[:8], 2))) == 145:
        bits = 7

    result_string = ''
    # iterate all group of 7 or 8 character in binary string based on bits
    # and append to result string
    for i in range(0, len(binary_string), bits):
        result_string += chr(int(binary_string[i:i + bits], 2))
    return result_string


def read_file(file_name):
    """
    This function takes file name as input and read file line by line and
    append to binary_str and return it
    :param file_name: 
    :return: 
    """
    binary_str = ''
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            binary_str += line.strip()
    return binary_str


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_file = sys.argv[1]
    print(binary_to_str(read_file(input_file)))
```

I am trying to pass in a text file with the binary message:

```
100100011001011101100110110011011110100000101011111011111110010110110011001000100001
```

Which is in a text file binary1.txt located in my pythonpractice folder along with my binary_to_string.py file.

The errors i receive from the terminal are as follows:

```
bthib@bthib-cyberstorm ~ $ cd pythonpractice

bthib@bthib-cyberstorm ~/pythonpractice $ python ./binary_to_string.py > binary1.txt

/usr/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in './binary_to_string.py'
```

Comment: The second one is caused by not typing the name of your script correctly.

Comment: I realize i made a typo the second time i tried to compile, i tried it again without the typo and it gave the error "can't find '__main__' module in './binary_to_string.py' @kindall

Comment: The error seems like you have a directory with name 'binary_to_string.py' in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Error// bash: ./binary_to_strong.py: No such file or directory :
Have you give a directory in your python script to call ?

It possible to use a file object to pass the binary value you want to the textfile

Comment: Sorry that error doesn't exist anymore, i just made a typo at that instance.

Comment: you try comment those line see is it no more error
     # if __name__ == '__main__':
    #input_file = sys.argv[1]
    #print(binary_to_str(read_file(input_file)))
This is just to confirmation where the error occurs

Comment: did you get it to work? i tried you changed and still got the  same error, you want me to comment out the last 2 lines?

Comment: start comment from #if __name__ == **** , last three line

Comment: I am still getting the same error, it must be something on my end and not the actual code that is incorrect then?

Comment: The thing you want achieve is write the binary string to a textfile ?

Comment: No i want this code to take a text file as input and convert the binary in the text file to string as output